# Sort text fields which contains numbers and text in ascending order

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying a sort a text field that has numeric values and text values together in ascending order.

Here below, Suite_Number__c is the text field on which I want the order to happen. Numeric fields first and then alpha is way I wanted it to be,all in ASC order. Also how can we have suite numbers like 30, 30B, 30A appear in ascending order like 30,30A,30B together.

I tried SOQL with the order by clause, didn't have any effect. The order that the query spits out as of now is just random, there is no order to it at all.

```
select Id,Suite_Number__c,Full_Name__c,Telephone_Number__c from Address_ColdCustomers__c WHERE Name LIKE : sTempSearchKey ORDER BY Suite_Number__c ASC
```

Please advise!

Comment: Suite_Number__c is not encrypted right?

Comment: No it is not, none of the fields are encrypted.

Comment: Not hearing from anyone on this, Is this something that is not possible?

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details.  The text field is Suite_Number__c, correct?  What is the exact order that you want to display -- numeric first and then alpha?  Please write out the desired order.  What is the order that you get with your query?

Comment: Hello @David, Suite_Number__c is the text field on which I want the order to happen.  Numeric fields first and then alpha is way I wanted it to be,all in ASC order. Also how can we have suite numbers like 30, 30B, 30A appear in ascending order like 30,30A,30B together.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/300499/edit) your post to include that detail and also What is the order that you get with your query?

Comment: Hello David, I have edited my original post.

Comment: Is Suite_Number__c by chance a picklist field or plain text?

Comment: Hi @Ronnie, its a plain text field.